# Jquery UI slider, setting values bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

i have 3 div's

```
<div id="slider-range1" class="slider-range"></div>
<div id="slider-range2" class="slider-range"></div>
<div id="slider-range3" class="slider-range"></div>
```

i have added the slider to these div's using class reference

```
$(function() {
        $(".slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            slide: function(event, ui) {

            }
        });
});
```

the ranges of each sliders are different. I want to add that dynamically

I tried

```
$("#slider-range1").slider('option','values',[1, 100]);
```

but it is not working :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried:

```
$('selector').slider( 'values' , index , value ); // index would be the square in the slider
```

in your example you could:

```
$("#slider-range1").slider('values', 0, 50);
$("#slider-range1").slider('values', 1, 100);
```

Comment: **Uncaught Error: no such method 'values' for slider widget instance**, this error i am getting when trying the above solution ! @Reigel

Answer (score 1):

`$('#slider-range').slider('option', 'min', 1);`

`$('#slider-range').slider('option', 'max', 100);`

**Updated according to poster's comment on this answer:**

Actually, your question contains an naswer :)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-range

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [75, 300],
});
```